# Word 2007: Duplicate a table with content control from one page to another

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

Is there a way to clone table with predefined style, fonts, content control etc. from one page to another page so that i can fill in different data in different tales. 
so for instance I wwould have, lets say, a table that shows Name, Age, Address of one person in one table. then the next page has the same table style but the information is different.

Is this possible? I found a way to clone rows/columns but not entire table.

I am using C# with OpenXML SDK 2.0. Any help in this subject would be much appreciated.

Thanks in anticipation.

regards

Answer (score 0):

this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197932%28v=office.12%29.aspx) may help

```
foreach (var order in customerOrderHistory)
    {
        TableRow rowCopy = (TableRow)theRow.CloneNode(true);
        rowCopy.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(0).Append(new Paragraph 
            (new Run (new Text(order.Contact.ToString()))));
        rowCopy.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(1).Append(new Paragraph 
            (new Run (new Text(order.NameOfProduct.ToString()))));
        rowCopy.Descendants<TableCell>().ElementAt(2).Append(new Paragraph 
            (new Run (new Text(order.Amount.ToString()))));
        theTable.AppendChild(rowCopy);
     }
```